# div containing map required to fill contents of page exactly

Tags: html, css, dictionary, leaflet, mapbox

I am new to CSS / HTML so excuse me if this is blindingly obvious.  I would like to avoid hard coding or using javascript for the below unless is it necessary.

I am creating a page which should not scroll and will fill the contents of the screen exactly.  The issue is that when I place a map onto the screen, the contents take up more of the screen than the page height and a scrollbar appears.

I have created a jsfiddle here which shows the problem, the height of the "outer" div should not ever exceed 70% of the size of the blue area but it seems the map itself always is the full 70% and any other divs add on to this size.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hxsm3/4/

```
#outer {
    ...
    height: 70%;
    width: 80%;
}

#map { 
    ...
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Additionally, the content surrounding the map is not static, so the size can not be predetermined and hard coded into the CSS.  I therefore need to get the map to take exactly the height it would take to fill the remainder of the page, no more, no less.

I assume this would be really simple but perhaps I just could not find the keyword I may be looking for.

Comment: not sure what the problem is...

Comment: sfietche, the problem is that the div with id "outer", i.e. the map + the divs above and below it should not total more than 70% of the blue area.  I.e. They should be confined to only use that space.  If you click on the green areas, they are removed - this is similar to the actual behaviour on the final product - when these are removed, it should STILL take a total of 70% of the blue are, no more, no less.  Does that explain it a little better?

Comment: are you saying the problem is when the green areas are present, the `#outer` `div` is taking up too much space?  If so, are you looking for a solution that dynamically adjusts the size of the map based on what else is within `#outer` `div`?

Comment: Yes - That sounds about right.  So total green area height + map should always be the same total height.  I would have expected that there would be a way for the map to take the remaining space after the green areas are put it without any javascript?

Comment: got it.  maybe my answer below helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically remove elements from your page while resizing your map to fill the emptied space, you'll want some javascript to help dynamically resize your map.

It wouldn't take much though...maybe something similar to the following:

```
$(".maynotexist").click(function() {
    var heightDifference = $(this).height();
    $(this).remove();
    // adjust mapHeight accordingly (based on height of element removed)
    var newMapHeight = $('#map').height() + heightDifference;
    $('#map').height(newHeight);
});
```

I created a [pretty rudimentary jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hxsm3/13/) that demonstrates how you might begin to approach this problem.

Comment: Thank you - I wanted to avoid javascript as it felt like it was simple enough layouting that it didn't need it. Are you saying its not possible with pure css / html? I have heard varied opinions on using tables for layout but could this be an option?